# High availability of Standalone Java Multi threaded application

Tags: java, windows-services, activemq-classic

We are using a Core Java APP with no WEBSERVER, which is MULTI-Threaded. We have a requirement where in ,our app is to be made highly available in the customers environment.
All the transactions in our app are majorly ActiveMQ(Java Messaging Services TCP connections) based i.e. we communicate with other apps using message Queues. We also have HTTP connections
For High-availability of ActiveMQ ,we have implemented it in Master/Slave Configuration(Active/Passive)
For High-availability of our App(Active/Active),we thought of deploying two instances of the app which will consume the messages parallelly,
but this implementaion will rule out our internal feature of retaining the message . We are acknowledging the message from ActiveMQ queue only if they are proccessed.
Hence having two instances running might result in duplication of the proccess for the corresponding message.

Please advice us on how to make our App Highly-available.
Does a load Balancer in Place solve our issue? Also,
Should we have to convert our Core Java App into services?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you exactly mean by retaining of messages?

Comment: Retaining a message implies keeping the message in the active mq message queues until it is processed.

Comment: ahh, that should not be a problem, Have posted answer

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want high availability of app, AND IF high availability of your app directly depends on high availability of ActiveMQ, then what you should really be doing is, having a single instance of App and multiple instances of activeMQ,

what this does is, even if one instance of ActiveMQ goes down, other might takeover(typical Master-slave configuration) and App will function as expected.

This topology will also not result in duplication of message processing,because at any point of time only one ActiveMQ instance will be associated with your app.

for load balncing you can have a look here(if it suits your requirements).

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19823-01/819-0215/loadb.html

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks vihar for your reply. We have already implemented the active mq master slave configuration. But now we want our app to be configured as master slave. Please provide us solutiom

Comment: yes for that load-balncing and failover is what you will need